# Use Python to get Baidu search result urls

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, urllib

I'm trying to get search results from Baidu.
But now I'm stucked here:

```
import sys
import urllib
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
question_word = "Hello"
url = "http://www.baidu.com/s?wd=" +     urllib.quote(question_word.decode(sys.stdin.encoding).encode('gbk'))
htmlpage = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlpage)
for child in soup.findAll("h3", {"class": "t"}):
    print child.contents[0]
```

This will return all the  tags that has the target urls.
I do not know how to use .get('href') to list out the actual urls

I'm new to Python thus might have some confusions over the basic concepts..
I'll really appreciate the help.

Comment: This question needs to include the structure being scraped. The search page may have changed over time or have become unavailable, making this question now unanswerable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for child in soup.findAll("h3", {"class": "t"}):
    print child.a.get('href')
```

use `.` to get the next `a` tag in the `h3` tag, then you can use `.get()`

Comment: I'm really sorry I accidentally clicked "This answer is not helpful" button TAT

Answer (score 1):

There are some options to grab `href`, here's two of them: `.a.get('href')` or `.a['href']`

You can also use [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) to grab `CSS` selectors and use `select()` or `select_one()` methods to find what you're looking for and iterate through them using `for loop`.

Code and [full example](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Baidu-scrape-URLs-search-results-bs4-pyhton-requests#.env):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; HD1913) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.105 Mobile Safari/537.36 EdgA/46.1.2.5140"
}

response = requests.get('https://www.baidu.com/s?tn=baidu&wd=lasagna', headers=headers).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')

for link in soup.select('.result .t a'):
  links = link['href']
  print(links)
```

Output:

```
http://www.baidu.com/link?url=HsRYa1X1Me8F9GY13KcqBcfFuLv1ST0OgGrTV-czCKVjRFlnzBIkhefpxX7Qy5a1vmfDn2sfZm_oJ9MB5dsthKQp8-oUt5QAQWjtTepQ46O
http://www.baidu.com/link?url=BShcWZT386OcLGiTRZZvHVYxk3c5RJg8xP7NmWyzzelEgMi4Udwsmkn_0HKwm3bAYwD4vijoRAAsPkfU03Gvv_
http://www.baidu.com/link?url=YYtyQWUvIzNvsul5yxH16yYtuvgQG7otyqUlc218FmFKR3It4jnLn69Iuk8h9wAx
http://www.baidu.com/link?url=l-_isPDZWm36Hu8otKlJYz6PM80wnr8gEXS9NcuQ-lj7xIWrIBCW6-s8J-ovtiZZeUqosqAOOMpSlclq2CHN7_
http://www.baidu.com/link?url=86Rh7aSzzMlVz6Upzra57OKMc4sMZkTgECNk9IQi493D6jDqtNYSSaYNHDSeXZ40zpU29RxRvq6W7xm4O8FNVq
http://www.baidu.com/link?url=91g1S6LBPAA3sXIU3b-OSsbNVYvBUS6iD6FzAoTdNS_NBQn1L5uHvvo8X8RialUm
http://www.baidu.com/link?url=wkVK0QjvpTMNxQuvIy--P8BHeW8oeSkBizDxP2JDtWcT4AZ5DCYd-DDLjWBwQ7Lj
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [Baidu Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/baidu-organic-results) from SerpApi.
It's a paid API with a free trial.

Code to integrate:

```
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
    "engine": "baidu",
    "q": "(意大利)千层面",
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()


for organic_result in results["organic_results"]:
  if 'link' in organic_result:
    print(f"Link: {organic_result['link']}")
```

Output:

```
Link: http://www.baidu.com/link?url=bvvL93wtWMZN2N7XNDAdcHv7-V4xk_ltvtDwQpIEGi8Cikedd2OTlCkiJU_sAJY-nvitYCHfwj9yP9FoyM2YwTYcwygddL1LGqNnf4RjmX35OE5GYNM1TMo4FIA70pIpyaPodDHyAUGxAFZAdoD9Nq
Link: http://www.baidu.com/link?url=5bldYEmDCmryDDeWYPjUO87EvQUYyaS5R1MmXhm7t9pReijqCgbkqP0N4wxukwDRmNya1_HQKn1flaWGQ5s5zeBgvIv1sDmeXziyyksttWtCZv488feUpO6Su3aKLJm--5RKj78YbxM2MYlCblC-RhAzyIPwPmD4ujkVnx2I9mhiWYyOp2F5JhCTM4p50qFf
Link: http://www.baidu.com/link?url=tOaRrtH80vM4w3Nvj81lE-HTgS22ZT5dDFb4mZb_mydsXNT502JrvDeFtmv92DJ-iO4XQ2x_RWPT383yfPN_5q
Link: http://www.baidu.com/link?url=-Oftww54gKeV5Y9Arv7Pb98F_J_wMJ-ZjAT8nCiDUG1KP9GgTUI6rttZwk1GUVeimShwiXUb6XQ0Avg6t45Ssq
Link: http://www.baidu.com/link?url=PXtVGPa_zrRvxOWHOXEdfmPdBONvR0bKiQ18pqZssqf3MD3EyfgZl0DF90wNpSvoLwHYajnd6yW73yNvYY8kiSDfakZjA8vHuT0G4hKsi6S
Link: http://www.baidu.com/link?url=vsamKJMS3JWKjipxbRZadTfqBDMUsYxp_jUzXZbZ4mXWPxH2G3lkl7crUt8huAMAdy4R-_T0BGF7zQwU8JOPPK
Link: http://www.baidu.com/link?url=0uIAbYhNuwLDNvyoD2bUusKPqt9Yh5Kw763DhNSlHE2f3WS0CnY5tZZgwRsihjJZTp4bN_2HDfIJ2MFggYFNdABt6FyV-Rnb-YCjzAf80SC
Link: http://www.baidu.com/link?url=Uwm9NtMcJGu4Mj4BN1nKyDUUERR1KXv9y9PJHzuo8PUdEY8wE6jxsc1sSuDkzIIR
Link: http://www.baidu.com/link?url=_ey4jd5jd0vxvTwIRhrFleI-q4hVk7yZG-aaEdW0BpgaeM_3jcxqSN_jWw3w5syB3V4xFWxzZDS6lZNoqwv8aOo6U269AfBME86GxQ3b_F7
Link: http://www.baidu.com/link?url=B6gRmV70secoV7cM_KcJnbJFzgFCpWV0ShwONC9t5fFuZlOkbirx5qYdIxDUq8jPxP4HhaQvSOxX_qMEglAs2_
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.

Comment: the resulted link is not the actual url, one need to decode it to get real url, but I guess this is impossible unless you use get(encrypted-url) and parse the response. However, this means you need to do it for every different link, this will quickly call for banning. https://developpaper.com/question/how-does-python-get-the-real-url-of-baidu-search-results/